# Inverted question/exclamation marks

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to type inverted question marks and exclamation marks in Ubuntu 15.04 and have tried AltGrt + ? and AltGrt + ! but all I get is: ? and ! respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what keyboard layout you are using!
It might be that in your layout they are in 4th level of the keyboard entry.
In that case, you should do `AltGr` + `Shift` + `?`

If you are using several layouts (icon on the top menu bar, near the time), you could try changing the keyboard layout to something different and set it back to your usual layout. Sometimes it's a little buggy.

Moreover, in many layouts they are several keys or key combinations printing the same characters maybe trying the other options would help.